# What is the correct usage of [downloadfile] and why do we have this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[downloadfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloadfile)

I just saw a Java question about downloading a file from the web. It used this peculiar tag. I googled it out to see if it some framework or some technology of which I am not aware of yet. The only result was a [.net method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netframework-4.8). What is the purpose of this tag?

Comment: Looks like a possible candidate for burnination.

Comment: @Script47: [downloadfile] to /dev/null

Comment: Even if it's a .NET method, it's really ambiguous which you can say by looking at the tag. You have java questions ([16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloadfile+java)) and R questions ([just 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloadfile+r)) and javascript ([16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloadfile+javascript)) questions, PHP questions ([15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloadfile+php)) python questions ([just 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloadfile+python))